# Is there a way to see what's inside the stdio.h or how it's implemented?

Tags: c++, c, header

Is there a way to see what's inside the stdio.h or how it's implemented?
I learned that the standard functions are declared in the stdio.h file
and I can't find it in my computer
plus I heard that there is another file where the body of the functions are all written,
which is called the stdio.c file.
Can anyone tell me WHERE this file is in my computer (I am using gcc compilier)
or anyway to see how it is implemented?

Comment: There are open source implementations as well as closed source implementations. [glibc](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/) is an Open Source and found on GitHub or Woboq.

Comment: Search & download `gnu libc` sources. [GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html)

Comment: Most likely your computer doesn't have the source code, only the compiled version. But as other people said, you can look up the source code or download it.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html

Comment: @Scheff'sCat THANK YOU everyone!!! Found exactly what I wanted

Comment: @Jolly what exactly did you find?

Comment: I just wanted to see how stdio.h was coded and I found it in this website
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/stdio.h.html

Comment: yes, you can find it. But I must warn you that the implementation is going to be messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the c++ header files are stored in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\"some_version"\ucrt` for Windows, and in `/usr/include` for linux. There you can find the `stdio.h` file and any other of the standard c++ header files.

Otherwise looking on the internet for `stdio.h` source code is also an option